# How Do I Count Number of Males and Females

Tags: mysql, count

I have the query as follows:

```
select d.question, b.response, count(b.response)
from sl_flow a
INNER JOIN ul_attempt_responses b on a.question_id = b.question_id and b.type = 1
INNER JOIN us_attempts c on c.id = b.attempt_id
INNER JOIN ss_questions d on d.id = a.question_id
where a.status = 1
and a.ckm_question = 0
and b.response 
group by a.question_id, b.response
order by a.question_order asc
```

The above gives me the questions that I have in the DB which are active and their responses and counts.

However I need a query that will give me number of males and females that answered each of the question. Therefore, I have another query that gives me the number of males and females which is:

```
SELECT 
concat(a.response, 's') as gender,
count(a.response) as count
FROM
ul_attempt_responses a
    INNER JOIN us_attempts b ON a.attempt_id = b.id
WHERE
a.question_id = 6 and a.type = 0 AND trim(a.response) != ''
GROUP by a.response;
```

I am not sure, how to do so. For the gender, the question_id is 6 and type on the `a` table has to be 0 (the `a` table is `ul_attempt_responses`).

This is what I got so far. However, it appears that the results I am getting may not be consistent:

```
SELECT
gender.question 
,coalesce(sum(case final.Response when 'male' then gender.total end),0) as 'Males'
,coalesce(sum(case final.Response when 'female' then gender.total end),0) as 'Females'
FROM
(SELECT
stats . *,
(CASE concat(stats.userid, stats.QuestionID, stats.type)
WHEN @curType THEN @curRow:=coalesce(@curRow, 0) + 1
ELSE @curROw:=1
AND @curType:=concat(stats.userid, stats.QuestionID, stats.type)
END) + 1 AS rank
FROM
(SELECT
d.question as Question,
a.user_id AS UserID,
c.question_id AS QuestionID,
c.type as Type,
c.response AS Response,
a.campaign_id as campaign_id
FROM
us_attempts a
INNER JOIN ul_attempt_responses c ON a.id = c.attempt_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN ss_profile_questions d ON c.question_id = d.id AND c.type = 0
LEFT OUTER JOIN sl_profile_flow f ON c.question_id = f.profile_question_id
RIGHT OUTER JOIN us_users g ON g.id = a.user_id
WHERE
f.status = 1
ORDER BY a.user_id , c.question_id , c.type , a.id desc) stats) final
INNER JOIN
(select b.user_id, c.question as question, count(1) as total
from ul_attempt_responses a
INNER JOIN us_attempts b on a.attempt_id = b.id
INNER JOIN ss_questions c on a.question_id = c.id and a.type = 1
group by b.user_id, c.id) gender on final.UserID = gender.user_id
where
final.rank = 2 and final.QuestionID = 6 and final.campaign_id = 3
group by gender.question;
```

Is there a way I can reduce the above query, or is there a better optimized way?

Comment: Seems like some data is missing in the queries. What is the structure of the tables?

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding your question, but if I were to guess, I'd assume you're looking for conditional aggregation -- perhaps with `sum` and `case`. . .

Comment: What my question is asking for is, a query, that will give me the question, and the count() of males and females that answered that question. More like for all the questions in the DB. Also, the gender is question_id 6 in the DB. The first query gives me all the questions answered, and the second gives me the number of males and females in the DB. So I need a query to combine the two in a way, that gives me number of males and females answered the question per question

Comment: Which is the 'gender' field? What format is it in? Where's all the detail that's required for anybody else to answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of sum and case/if to get the counts. Given your full table structures are not clear, I am assuming you have a table (or an SQL that can produce a set of rows) with the following fields:

```
response_id
question_id
response
```

Then an SQL such as

```
select question_id
   , response
   , sum(if(gender='M',1,0)) as males
   , sum(if(gender='F',1,0)) as females 
from (select q.question_id
   , q.response
   , g.response as gender from answers as q 
left join answers as g on q.response_id=g.response_id and g.question_id=6
where q.question_id!=6) as t 
group by question_id, response
```

would give you a result of the form

```
question_id,response,males,females
1,A,1,2
1,B,1,0
2,A,0,1
2,B,1,1
2,C,1,0
```

To explain the code, the sub query produces a set of rows for each response with the question mapped with the gender question's response. In the main select statement the if statement produces a 1 for the specific gender in the proper column and summing them up gives you how many of that specific gender responded to that question.

**EDIT**
As suggested by @Strawberry, the shorter version would be

```
select q.question_id
     , q.response_id
     , sum(g.response='M') as males
     , sum(g.response='F') as females 
  from answers as q 
  left 
  join test as g 
    on q.response_id = g.response_id 
   and g.question_id = 6 
 where q.question_id != 6 
 group 
    by q.question_id
     , q.response
```

Comment: Or if less code is your thing: sum(gender='F') female. And the sub query seems redundant

Comment: Would like to see the right solution @Strawberry. Thanks for the previous tip which I didn't know was possible.

Comment: I'll retract that remark. The q's look a lot like g's on my little screen!

Comment: I hate working on tiny screens just for the same reason.

Comment: I have edited my code, with the solution I am using, but the results are not consistent. I only get the correct results when I run my query twice!

Comment: If the answers are inconsistent, it is usually a case of how MySQL picks rows in a group by. I don't know the full extent of your table structure, but if you are picking other column values related to a group by, MySQL will pick a random row's value for the other column not in the group by. This is usually solved by adding additional conditions into the join logic.